# Java Android, wifi, Probe Request, 802.11

Tags: java, android, wifi

The goal we want to achieve is control over **Probe Request** from a Java application level (under Android of course).

The standard Java API provides a set of options to check response, however we would like to have control over sending it.

May be I do not seek it properly within standard packages like android.net.wifi

May be a direct solution is not attainable, thus, one should kludge something around?

I will appreciate any hint how to solve it or where to look for a solution.